# Consecutive visits is updating only after page reload

Tags: discussion, visited-days

Why do consecutive visits counter is updating only after profile page reload?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open stackoverflow profile page (first time, today)
2. See number of consecutive visits
3. Update page (second visit today)
4. Number of consecutive visits is incremented by one

Why it is not incremented just after first page touch?

Comment: Now, how is this a feature request? You are not asking for any feature, right?

Comment: Sorry you are right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why? Because caching.

We cache the user page for one minute, so changes will only appear after that minute.

Why do we cache? Because performance.

Comment: Why do we need performance. Because yes.

Comment: What are you using for caching?

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich - A bunch of things. From static members to Redis.

Comment: @Oded love it..